# Problem to view SWF in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

> hello expert
>   I have create one application (name is "**aaa**")in which I have load *SWF* file from assets folder.i have install
>   "**Adobe flash player 10.1**" by this command
>   "**adb -e install -r adobe flsh player 10.1.apk**" by command line.
>   but problem is when i click on my application(aaa), not aable to view swf file in emulator.
>   Please anyone help me.
>   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing : adobe flash player play a background services which is give only flash effect.
second thing : you have to try it in device.
third thing : if you really need to load in emulator then use adobeAir emulator.it is ready to play any flash content